# Placeholder Margin on Xamarin Forms Editor using Custom Renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I've an Editor on a page in my Xamarin Forms Project and I'm looking to amend the placeholder text position by adding a slight margin.

I was able to add a margin to the text the user types (but not the placeholder) using "TextContainerInset" in my iOS Custom renderer.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
        {
           
                base.OnElementChanged(e);
                this.Control.InputAccessoryView = null;
                this.Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
                this.Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
                this.Control.Layer.BorderWidth = (nfloat)0.5;
                this.Control.TextContainerInset = new UIEdgeInsets(15,15,15,15);    
          
        }
```

However, this inset doesn't apply to the placeholder position.

Is there a way to move the placeholder position using the custom renderer?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the padding like:

```
       public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged (e);
    
                if (Control != null) {
            Control.LeftView = new UIView(new CGRect(0,0,15,0));
            Control.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
            Control.RightView = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 15, 0));
            Control.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;
                }
            }
}
```

**Workaournd for editor:**

warp the editor in the frame and set the padding like:

```
<StackLayout Margin="20">
    <Frame CornerRadius="10" BorderColor="Gray" HeightRequest="50" Padding="5,10,5,10" HasShadow="False">
        <Editor Placeholder="Enter the editor text" ></Editor>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I get "'UITextView' does not contain a definition for 'LeftView' and no accessible extension method 'LeftView' accepting a first argument of type 'UITextView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". It's an Editor rather than an entry so would this be making the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying **UITextView** does not implement the **Placeholder**. However if you look at the EditorRenderer code which derives from UITextView, Xamarin has implemented the Placeholder there.

```
private UILabel _placeholderLabel;
```

By using reflection, I can get a pointer to the **UILabel _placeholderLabel**, but I can't for the life of me move it.

If someone can help me move the **UILabel**, I believe we have the answer!

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Editor> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control != null)
    {
        editor = e.NewElement as EditorEx;

        //Use reflection to access private placeholder in parent
        //https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6f0898/how-to-access-a-private-member-of-a-class-from-other-class/
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo receivedObject = typeof(EditorRenderer).GetFields(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)[1];

        _placeholderLabel = receivedObject.GetValue(this) as UILabel;

        _placeholderLabel.Text = "move me!!; //this works
        _placeholderLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green; //this works

        //put it on another message to see if that solves it (it doesn't)
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            //HELP NEEDED HERE!!!
            //_placeholderLabel.Frame = new CGRect(-15, -10, 500, 30); //doesn't work
            //_placeholderLabel.Bounds = new CGRect(-15, -10, 500, 30); //doesn't work
            _placeholderLabel.LayoutMargins = new UIEdgeInsets(-15, -10, 5, 5); //doesn't work

        });
    }
}
```